# Qt Creator: how to move cursor in column edit mode?

Tags: editor, qt-creator

In Qt Creator, by using Alt-Shift-Up or Alt-Shift-Down keyboard shortcut I can enter column edit mode and edit multiple lines simultaneously by back-spacing, pasting, deleting, and typing.

I want to move the column selection cursor left or right. If I press left or right arrows, the editor exits column edit mode and leaves the cursor either at the top or bottom of where the column selection was.

How can I move the cursor left or right without modifying characters and without exiting column edit mode?